# Vector finding out the value of P?

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

Given two force 2P and P , when the first one is doubled , i.e 4P and the 8 is added to the second one i.e P+8 , the direction of the resultant remains unaltered . What is the value of P ?

N.B : I have been solved this problem over and over many times , but every time doing it again , I can't do it and had to take the solution of the exercise. But now I have no solution in my hand , so I am posting in here . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear exactly what you are asking but will assume it is this: find $P$ such that the vectors $(2P,P)$ and $(4P,P+8)$ have the same direction.

Two vectors have the same direction if their coordinates are proportional:
$$\frac{4P}{2P}=\frac{P+8}{P}\ .$$
Solving the equation gives $P=8$.

Comment: any other way to do it ? like applying the resultant angle formula tan(A) = 2Psin(B)/(P+2Pcos(B))

Comment: Don't know that formula.  Sorry, can't suggest any other method.

Comment: never mind , its tan(A) = (2P*SIN(B))/(P+2P*COSB)) formula